# Error while running ant build from eclipse on Linux. Cannot call wsimport from ant

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, ant

Recently I switched to Linux Mint 15 and I have problems with Eclipse and ant.
This is the piece of ant script that is causing the trouble:

```
                <exec osfamily="unix" executable="wsimport">
                    <arg line="${prefix}/${jaxb.resources}/${jaxb.schema@{i}} -s ${prefix}/${jaxb.src} -p ${jaxb.package@{i}} -wsdllocation ${jaxb.schema@{i}} -b ${prefix}/jaxb-bindings.xml -Xdebug -verbose -Xnocompile" />
                </exec>
```

However, during the build, using the ant in eclipse, I am getting the following error:

```
Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "wsimport": error=2, No such file or directory
```

I understand that this is due to that Eclipse is unable to find wsimport tool that is the part of the JDK. However, if I run this ant script inside a terminal, everything passes correctly. 
My .bashrc has PATH variable set to jdk/bin folder and wsimport is accessible through terminal. Eclipse uses ant version that is installed on my machine (not the embedded one) and project is built using JDK compiler (not embedded in one). I use Oracle's JDK 1.7.0_45 64-bit.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

I installed my JDK manually (not by package installer) in /usr/lib/jvm/jdk. Configured it using update-alternatives and set JAVA_HOME and PATH variables in my user's .bashrc. Like I said, ant script works from terminal, but not from Eclipse (on ant window) Maybe eclipse is not aware of PATH variable in .bashrc...

Comment: Perhaps try an give the full path to the executable. A gotcha is that you might have to restart Eclipse in order to pick up the new environment.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this ant script must be portable. Every machine that has correct java PATH variable should run this. However, for some reason, Eclipse ant seems not to pick variables correctly. I installed my JDK manually, not by package installer. Maybe it has something to do with that.

Answer (score 2):

(It's an old question, but maybe this will help others in the future.)
You can run wsgen and wsimport with Ant tasks.  I'm not familiar with all of your variables, so my example just does its own thing.  It requires variables:

- metro.home - the location of webservices-tools.jar
- build.classpath - the classpath of dependent jar files
- build.classes - the classpath of the @WebService class
- basedir - the location of where you're writing your wsgen and wsimport files

Here's the example.

```
<!-- setup Metro tooltime classpath -->
<path id="tool.cp">
    <path refid="runtime.cp"/>
    <pathelement location="${metro.home}/webservices-tools.jar"/>
</path>

<!--
    Setup Wsimport ant task. You would use this task in WSDL to Java case
    to compile a WSDL and generate Java classes.
-->
<taskdef name="wsimport" classname="com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsImport">
    <classpath refid="tool.cp"/>
</taskdef>

<!--
    Setup Wsgen ant task. You would use this task in Java to WSDL case to
    generate a WSDL or wrapper classes.
-->
<taskdef name="wsgen" classname="com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsGen">
    <classpath refid="tool.cp"/>
    <classpath refid="build.classpath"/>
</taskdef>

<target name="wsimport">
    <wsgen sei="com.company.app.ws.Authorize"
        classpath="${build.classes}"
        sourcedestdir="${basedir}/wsgen/src"
        destdir="${basedir}/wsgen/classes"
        keep="true" verbose="true" genwsdl="true" resourcedestdir="wsgen">
        <classpath refid="build.classpath"/>
    </wsgen>
    <wsimport verbose="true" keep="true"
        destdir="${basedir}/wsimport/classes"
        sourcedestdir="${basedir}/wsimport/src"
        wsdl="${basedir}/wsgen/AuthorizeService.wsdl"
    />
</target>
```

NOTE: This also works for me when launching the Ant script from Jenkins running on RedHat.

NOTE: If you try to run Ant using external tools in Eclipse, you may have problems if you choose a JRE e.g. "jre7" for the JRE in the External Tools Configuration; better to configure and use the JDK e.g. "jdk1.7.0_80".  Also, add "tools.jar" as an additional Classpath entry in the External Tool Configuration.